# Unable to Remove from ObservableCollection<object>

Tags: c#, linq

Having this observable collection:

```
ObservableCollection<Article> Articles;
```

I'm trying to delete a specific article. This is how I'm doing it:

```
Article selectedArticle = Articles.Where(x => x.Id == EditArticle_Id).FirstOrDefault();

if (selectedArticle != null)
{
     bool deleted = Articles.Remove(selectedArticle);
}
```

But deleted is always false. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: there are no wrong in the code. You need to look at how you filled the Articles and EditArticle_Id values